# Classifying the algebraic structure on endomorphism sets

Tags: ct.category-theory, universal-algebra, operads

This is motivated by defining modules in a general sense, which is an appropriate homomorphism from $R$ to $\textrm{End}(X)$. If $X$ comes from different categories, the endomorphism set will have different algebraic structures. If $X$ is an abelian group, then $\textrm{End}(X)$ is naturally a ring.
The question is, can we systematically find all the algebraic operations available on the endomorphism set, and the equations between them?

More precisely, given an algebraic theory, we can define suitable sets of "natural" $n$-ary operations, which forms a Cartesian operad (or a Lawvere theory). Can we find a nice presentation of this operad, given a presentation of the original algebraic theory, perhaps even algorithmically? I can think of the naturality in a number of ways using abstract nonsense, so I'm not sure which one should be used.

A subquestion would be to deal with the empty algebraic theory, whose models are just sets. So we want to define a notion of "natural" $(X \to X)^n \to (X \to X)$ such that the only elements are the obvious ones, bijective with the set of words with alphabet size $n$.

- If we define $\textrm{End} : \mathsf{Core}(\mathsf{Set}) \to \mathsf{Set}$ and look at natural transformations $\textrm{End}^n \to \textrm{End}$, then there will be unwanted elements. To see this, consider $n = 1$, unpack the definitions and we see that it's about the endomorphism of $G$-sets, where $G$ is the symmetric group. So a natural transformation could have a component $\eta_2 (f) = \textrm{swap} \circ f \circ \textrm{swap}$, where $\textrm{swap} : 2 \to 2$ is the swapping isomorphism. Since this isomorphism is in the center of $\mathfrak S_2$, naturality is preserved.
- We can consider the category $\mathsf{End} = \mathsf{Fun}(\mathbf B\mathbb N, \mathsf{Set})$, whose objects are sets equipped with an endomorphism and morphisms are commutative squares, and look at natural transformations $\textrm{Id}_{\textsf{End}} \to \textrm{Id}_{\textsf{End}}$ (this is the unary case for simplicity). This indeed yields the desired result, because composing with the functor $\textsf{End} \to \textsf{Set}$ forgetting the endomorphism, we get a natural transformation between representable functors $よ(\mathbb N, +1) \to よ(\mathbb N, +1)$, which by Yoneda consists of only the natural transforms "compose $k$ times". For $n$-ary operations, we swap $\mathbf B \mathbb N$ out by the monoid freely generated by $n$ elements, and a similar argument follows.

Does these carry through to more complicated algebraic structures?

Comment: There is some related material in our preprint https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.09006.pdf, with examples focused maybe one level down from what you are thinking about

Comment: You’ve framed the question as “what is the algebraic theory of endomorphisms of a model of a given algebraic theory”, but considering your examples we could as well ask “what are the endomorphism objects in a $V$-enriched category”, which is a much easier question whose answer is simply “a monoid in $V$.” Do you think the same phenomenon arises in cases that don’t fit this model?

Comment: @KevinArlin But not all monoids will be endomorphism objects, right? It takes non-trivial work to establish whether there will be more equational axioms (since we are only interested in the algebraic theory). Also, how can we use this framework to determine the extra algebraic operations that may arise? For instance, I should be able to determine that the endomorphisms of groups only form a monoid, but that of the abelian groups form a ring. Note how adding equational laws to the original theory gives rise to new algebraic operations.

Comment: @Trebor Every monoid is certainly an endomorphism object in some $V$-category, though it may not be an endomorphism object in $V$ itself. But I don't think you care that the endomorphisms of a set form a monoid-of-full-endomorphisms, since that's not even an algebraic concept--you just care that they form a monoid. (Probably! I guess you *could* be asking what's the strongest algebraic theory of which full endomorphism monoids are all models, and I'm not sure what to say about that.)

Comment: You can use this thinking to determine that endomorphisms of groups only form a monoid because there is no natural group structure on the set of homomorphisms between two groups. The algebraic theories such that the homomorphisms between two models naturally form another model are exactly those for which every operation is a homomorphism.

Comment: @KevinArlin There is no natural group structure, indeed. But what if there were some complicated 100-ary operation that happens to be homomorphic? I have determined for groups that this is not the case, but is there a general method?

Comment: In his paper on, among other things. the tensor product of algebraic theories, Freyd makes a claim which I interpret as that the largest algebraic theory over which a category can be enriched is that whose $n$-ary operations are the natural transformations from the encounter $x\mapsto x^n$ to the identity. The simplest examples are $+$, as a natural transformation out of the squaring endofunctor of an abelian group, as well as multiplication by a central element of $G$ as a natural endomorphism of the identity functor of $G$-sets or modules. Perhaps that’s mostly satisfactory?

Comment: In terms of algebraic theories this is just the largest subtheory spanned by the operations which are homomorphisms, which the nLab calls the centre of the theory. I don’t see any evidence that people have results on how to efficiently compute the center of a theory though it seems like a reasonably interesting problem. Anyway, see Freyd here: https://denotational.co.uk/scans/freyd-algebra-valued-functors-in-general-and-tensor-products-in-particular.pdf